# What type of file do i use for NSMutableDictionary withcontentofURL?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I want to fill a NSMutableDictionary with content out of a URL File. What type file must it be and how must it be structured?

```
NSMutableDictionary *myMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
    initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/list.txt"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in the [XML property list](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH6-SW1) format <sup>[1](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_41)</sup>:

> An URL that identifies a resource containing a string representation of a property list whose root object is a dictionary. The dictionary must contain only property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary).

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303) for an overview of the property list types.

E.g. the following file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>A</key><string>something</string>
    <key>B</key><integer>42</integer>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

... becomes a dictionary containing:

```
{
  A = something;
  B = 42;
}
```

Comment: Also, it can be an old-style dictionary format just containing `"key1" = "value1"; "key2" = "value2"` just like a `Localizable.strings` file.

Comment: Strings files aren't plists & the old-style format is heavily deprecated.  Don't use it.

Comment: @bbum: If Strings files aren't plists, why does it produce this error when not formatted properly: `23/05/10 11:53:52 AM App[74572] CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary.` Also, the documentation says that it is a property list representation. If it's so heavily deprecated why is it still being used for strings tables . . .

Comment: Implementation detail; the parser for string lists was borrowed from the old-school plist parser, but special cased for string lists..  Plists require that the outermost item is a collection -- a dictionary, IIRC.

Comment: @bbum: "Heavily" deprecated? Where did you read that? While old-style plist is [supported for legacy reason](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/propertylists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html), there's no sign it will go away soon. And since when "strings is a plist" is an implementation detail? It's [clearly documented](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html).

Comment: I don't know about the deprecation part, but the documentation only officially mentions plists being supported for `NSDictionary`. The i18n doc only mentions that a plist format can also be used for strings files, which doesn't imply the reverse.

Comment: From the docs: "*Important:* The `NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat` constant is not supported for writing. It can be used only for reading old-style property lists."  and "OpenStep format (use of this format is discouraged)."